# TextFormField not moving up when keyboard is appearing in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a message details page in which some information is there, then message threads are displayed (sent and received messages) and then the "TextFormField" is there for message typing. But when I tap on the text field to type and the keyboard is appearing, the content of the page is not moved up and the text field remains hidden under they keyboard. I tried every possible solutions like "resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true" in the Scaffold, setting the "android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"", keeping the whole body content in "SingleChildScrollView". But nothing is working. Please help regarding this.

This is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color _resolvedColor = Colors.redAccent;
    String _closedstatus = "Closed";
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: Constants.APPBAR_HEIGHT,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: const Text("Query Details", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white)),
      ),
     
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        child : Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
        LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
            double screenheight = constraints.maxHeight;
            return Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    initialData: null,
                    future: mProDetails,
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        var id = snapshot.data!.id;
                        var qrsno = snapshot.data!.qrsno;
                        var priority = snapshot.data!.priority;
                        var postedOn = snapshot.data!.postedOn;
                        var postedBy = snapshot.data!.postedBy;
                        var department = snapshot.data!.department;
                        var idealClosureDt = snapshot.data!.idealClosureDt;
                        var question = snapshot.data!.question;
                        var isClosed = snapshot.data!.isClosed;
                        var prioChangedByStakeholdr = snapshot.data!.prioChangedByStakeholdr;
                        var initialPriority = snapshot.data!.initialPriority;
                        var prioChangeDt = snapshot.data!.prioChangeDt;
                        var queryinfo = snapshot.data!.threads;

                        if(isClosed == '1'){
                          _resolvedColor = Colors.green;
                          _isVisibleMsgBox = false;
                          _closedstatus = "Closed";
                        }
                        else{
                          _resolvedColor = Colors.redAccent;
                          _isVisibleMsgBox = true;
                          _closedstatus = "Open";
                        }

                        _msgidcontroller.text = id;
                        return Column(
                            //keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text("${qrsno}", style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 14,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                                              )
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text(_closedstatus, style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 13,
                                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                                      color: _resolvedColor,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                                              )
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10)
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text("${priority}", style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 13,
                                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                                              )
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text("Ideal Closure Date: ${idealClosureDt}", style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 13,
                                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                                              )
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10)
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                  child: Text("${department}", style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 13,
                                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                                              ),
                                            ]
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    (prioChangedByStakeholdr == '1') ?
                                    Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10)
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                      child: Text("Initial: ${initialPriority}, Changed: ${prioChangeDt}", style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 12,
                                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic))
                                                  )
                                                ]
                                            ),

                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                        : Text(''),
                                    Divider(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade400
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        height: 300,
                                        child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                            child: ListView(
                                          children: [
                                            Align(
                                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: 250,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                                ),
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                                child : Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Align(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                      child:
                                                      Text("${question}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                                    ),
                                                    Align(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                      child:
                                                      Text("${postedBy}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,)),
                                                    ),
                                                    Align(
                                                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                                        child:
                                                        Text("${postedOn}", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,))
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            ListView.builder(
                                              shrinkWrap: true,
                                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                              itemCount: queryinfo.length,
                                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                var myqueries = queryinfo[index];
                                                return Container(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                                                  child: Align(
                                                    alignment: (myqueries.sentbyme == "1" ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight),
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      width: 250,
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                                        color: (myqueries.sentbyme == "1" ? Colors.grey.shade200 : Colors.red[50]),
                                                      ),
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Align(
                                                            alignment: (myqueries.sentbyme == "1" ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight),
                                                            child: Text(myqueries.msg, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                                                          ),
                                                          Align(
                                                            alignment: (myqueries.sentbyme == "1" ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight),
                                                            child:
                                                            Text(myqueries.sender, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,)),
                                                          ),
                                                          Align(
                                                              alignment: (myqueries.sentbyme == "1" ? Alignment.topLeft : Alignment.topRight),
                                                              child:
                                                              Text(myqueries.msgdate, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,))
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        )
                                    ),
                                        ]
                                    ),

                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),

                              ),
                              const Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                visible: _isVisibleMsgBox,
                                child:
                                Align(
                                  //alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 72.0,
                                    //alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:3.0), // Added padding for spacing
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Form(
                                          key: _formKey,
                                          child: Expanded(
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Visibility(
                                                  visible: false,
                                                  child: TextFormField(
                                                    controller: _msgidcontroller,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                TextFormField(
                                                  controller: _msgcontroller,
                                                  autocorrect: false,
                                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                    hintText: "Type your reply...",
                                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                                                    fillColor: Colors.blue,

                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                                          iconSize: 30.0,
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                sendMessage(context, _msgcontroller.text, _msgidcontroller.text);
                                              });
                                            }
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]
                        );
                      }
                      else {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red[800]),
                        );
                      }
                    }),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        ]
      ),
      ),
        )
      );
  }
```

Comment: You can try adding a bottom padding with `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + <some offset>`.

Comment: In which widget?

Comment: The `TextFormField` widget that you want to move up when the keyboard shows. And/or any other widget you want moving up.

Comment: As you are already using the singlechildscrollview, have you tried with           resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, and the immediate column to singlechildscrollview to have the default of mainAxisSize, which is mainAxisSize:  MainAxisSize.max?

Comment: Share UI Snippet of what you're trying to build & reduce the code to minimal reproducible code to give brief about your desired functionality

Comment: 3nws, I can't add "padding" to a TextFormField. Added to the Container which contains the text field like this: padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:3.0, left: 12, right:10, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom) and it is giving error